# Is it possible to remove variable from symfony url?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

```
/category/{id}/{categoryName}

localhost:8000/category/2/tours-and-travels 
localhost:8000/category/tours-and-travels //want to have this url.
```

Is it possible to remove id as shown above url?

Twig

```
<a class="nav-link text-white" href="{{ path('category_with_id',{'id': category.id, 'categoryName': category.name|slug('-')  }) }}">
        {{ category.name }}
    </a>
```

I know we can do this with the help of unique slug, but is it possible with id?

Comment: don't know what you mean. if the categoryName/category.name is unique, it is for all intents and purposes like a slug. You might have to tell some parameter converter how to fetch the category by its name, which is documented a lot. If it's not unique, however, your users might have a bad experience ...

Comment: you said "I know we can do this with the help of unique slug, but is it possible with id?" if you d'ont like to show the id in the url so use an Uid

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you trying to create a different [route?](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes). If this is true, it is better to change your question's Title, to better express it and doing so, attract a lot more people to answer you here.